# How to get fields from list of objects and set to another collection of object

Tags: java, spring, generics, java-8

Here, I have to get fields from list of objects and set to another collection of object

```
class RoomType {

private List<RatePlan> ratePlans = null;


}

class RatePlan {

private String ratePlanCode;
private String ratePanName;
}

=============================
to map to...

class TravelResponse {

private Collection<RatePlan> ratePlans = null;


}

class RatePlan {

private String ratePlanCode;
private String ratePanDescription;
}
```

RoomType contains the data, this data has to be mapped to TravelResponse.
RoomType -> RatePlan is list and TravelResponse -> RatePlan is collection

Mapping should be .....
RoomType.RatePlan.ratePlanCode = TravelResponse.RatePlan.ratePlanCode
RoomType.RatePlan.ratePanName  = TravelResponse.RatePlan.ratePanDescription

Comment: So please show us your attempt at solving this for yourself.  (The mapping looks straightforward, even trivial, so we need to know what about is giving you problems.)

Comment: @StephenC Here, Class RatePlan is same in both the packages with some change in fields. so, importing the RatePlan class is confusing...

Comment: You should not have two different versions of the `RatePlan` class.  Use a different name for the two classes ... or at least, different package names.  That is probably the solution to your problem.   (I noticed that, but I thought ... "Nah.  It has got to be a typo!")  The point is that unless you do some nasty tricks with dynamic class loaders, you won't be able to load both versions of the class into the same JVM.   You should just not go down that rabbit hole.  It is just a bad, bad, idea.